# Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)

Tags: mysql, django

I have a Django application whose database is in SQLite. I'm trying to migrate to MySQL. I created a dump file of my existing database using `manage.py dumpdata > datadump.json`

I updated my Database Settings as follows

```
'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'appname_db',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '3306',
    }
```

But I'm getting the `Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (10061)` error now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to configure your MySQL server in order to use MySQL database. SQLite is file based database which works out of the box.